# Foreign key as part of composite primary key

Tags: mysql, composite-key

I would like to have a kind of cascading primary key like given below.

Root table:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `root` (
  `id` MEDIUMINT UNSIGNED ZEROFILL NOT NULL auto_increment
PRIMARY KEY (`id`))
ENGINE = InnoDB;
```

Parent table:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `parent` (
  `id_root` MEDIUMINT UNSIGNED ZEROFILL NOT NULL,
  `id` INT UNSIGNED ZEROFILL NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (`id_root`,`id`),
CONSTRAINT `fk_root`
    FOREIGN KEY (`id_root`)
    REFERENCES `root` (`id`)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION)
ENGINE = InnoDB;
```

Child table:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `child` (
  `id_root` MEDIUMINT UNSIGNED ZEROFILL NOT NULL,
  `id_parent` INT UNSIGNED ZEROFILL NOT NULL,
  `id` SMALLINT UNSIGNED ZEROFILL NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (`id_root`,`id_parent`,`id`),
CONSTRAINT `fk_parent`
    FOREIGN KEY (`id_root`,`id_parent`)
    REFERENCES `parent` (`id_root`,`id`)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION)
ENGINE = InnoDB;
```

For INSERT statements the FOREIGN KEY part will be given, e.g. like:

```
INSERT INTO `child` (`id_root`, `id_parent`) VALUES (00000001, 00000001);
```

Unfortunately I run into 2 issues:

1. `id` of child table is set to 0 for first insert (even though declared as NOT NULL)
2. second insert with same `id_root` and `id_parent` is not taking place (guess due to primary key violation with `id`=0, for some reason mysql is not throwing an error like normally)

I have played with UNIQUE KEY instead of PRIMARY KEY, but same result. Auto_increment of `id` is rejected by the engine when creating the table.

Apart from giving the `id` value e.g. through triggers, is there another way to make this work ?

Comment: NOT NULL doesn't grantee that a column cannot have zero in it. create another index to the id column and assign auto_increment to it.

Comment: This approach works in principle, but id is incremented irrespective of id_root and id_parent. I am looking for an implementation where id is incremeted per id_root/id_parent combination